# How to assign callback when the user resizes a QMainWindow?

Tags: qt, qwidget

Neither I could find a tutorial-like scheme for a resize event on QMainWindow, nor I did see any option for adding resize event in the drop-down menu at the Qt design window.

I am new to Qt. I'd like to write a slot function for a QMainWindow resize event. Is there such event? How can I do this?

Comment: When I wrote this question, probably only Qt C++ existed. Since then PyQt was born, feel free to answer it for python as well. (although at the moment I don't have access to any of these)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

There is a [resize event](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qresizeevent.html).  In order to perform custom handling of the event, you'll need to create your own resize event handler.  In your case, you would need to create a class that derives from `QMainWindow` and reimplement the [`resizeEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) function.  Your code would look something like this:

```
void MyMainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* event)
{
   QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event);
   // Your code here.
}
```

The [Qt Scribble example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html) also has an example of overriding the resize event (though not on the main window).

Comment: I'd put the personal code before calling QMainWindow::resizeEvent(event) and not after because you can get information from this event before passing it to QMainWindow. Or even modify it before passing to QMainWindow.

Answer (score 6):

This works in Qt5 with me f.e. to resize the icon in a QTableWidget:

```c++
mainWindow.h
...
private:
void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*);
...

mainWindow.cpp
...
void mainWindow::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent*)
{
    tableWidget->setIconSize(QSize(tableWidget->size()/7)); //7 or whatever number you need it to get the full icon size
}
```

Comment: resizeEvent() is not a slot.

Answer (score 1):

In PyQt5 try the following:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PyQt5 import QtGui as qtg

class MainWindow(qtw.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(600, 600)
        # your code

    def resizeEvent(self, e: qtg.QResizeEvent):
        # your code
```