# How can u resizing font size form qlabel when I changed mainwindow?

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt5

When I using QFont to change font size from qlabel and It'll worked.

But if I changed mainwindow It have same size.

How can I resizing font size when mainwindow changed.

c++/Qt creator

Thanks :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for but maybe helpful: [SO: How to automatically increase/decrease text size in label in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42690033/7478597)

Comment: You can reimplement resizeEvent function for your QMainWindow class and set font in there, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12828825/how-to-assign-callback-when-the-user-resizes-a-qmainwindow)